# New installation fluorescent green?

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, graphics

Hey I’m a new Linux user and I wanted to try the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When I did this I made the bootable usb drive booted from it and all of the graphics were fine until until I selected try Ubuntu. The screen then got a fluorescent green tint. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The computer is an Asus ROG Strix G10DK, runs Windows 10 without an issue. Has a NVIDIA graphics card and an AMD Ryzen 5 3600X 6-Core processor.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 now uses the display driver Wayland by default, even when using nVidia graphical cards. Support for nVidia cards is very recent, and it seems that issues remain.

For now, you may work around by running Ubuntu on the traditional Xorg display server. To do that, log out. On the login screen, before entering your password, click the cog wheel in the bottom right and select "Ubuntu on Xorg".

[image]